# Can't find CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX folder

Tags: windows, cmake, azerothcore

I'm following the guide from:

http://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/Installation

I'm having issues at the very last instructions under "compiling on windows" where I am asked to move a series of DLLs to a folder called `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`. I cannot find this folder, despite getting no errors from the compiler? visual studio I don't think things are building properly.

I get 3 warnings when compiling in visual studio,

`Warning LNK4221 This object file does not define any previously undefined public symbols, so it will not be used by and link operation that consumes this library scripts Build\src\server\scripts\zone_alterac_mountains.obj 1`

`Warning LNK4221 This object file does not define any previously undefined public symbols, so it will not be used by any link operation that consumes this library scripts \Build\src\server\scripts\zone_burning_steppes.obj 1`

`Warning C4715 'WorldSocket::ProcessIncoming': not all control paths return a value game c:\users\frith\azerothcore\src\server\game\server\worldsocket.cpp 727`

I've restarted the entire process a few times and have made no progress. I'm under the impression I should see something in the destination folder, it is empty.

After some digging I found this in an error log in build/CMakefies

`\Build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CheckIncludeFile.c(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pthread.h': No such file or directory [\Build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_0e035.vcxproj]`

I'm totally stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` is the location where **you** selected to install AC.

As the guide says:

> Change CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX to the location where you will run your server from.

this happens in chapter `3) Compiling` -> `Compiling on Windows`

Comment: I should have used a different word than destination folder, I mean the folder I select in cmake as the folder from which I will run the server is totally empty. Or do you mean the folder I specified is the cmake_install_prefix folder?

Comment: they should be the same